# How to avoid initial lag after input using Material UI

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, material-ui

**Context**
I have a carousel of MUI cards for a website that I'm building that is a box using a [stack as it's underlying component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iB0g6.png). A problem that's come up is that whenever I try to scroll, there's at least a 4 second lag before seeing any new render. I tried

1. cropping down the images
2. compressing them
3. converting to `.webp`'s
4. moving the logic into one place instead of passing props

**Thouhgts**

- Memoizing the component works as a band-aid after the initial lag and
  it scrolls as it should after but I'm assuming that's not the correct way
  to do this.
- *(Idea)* After looking back into the docs for an alternative I figured
  virtualizing the list might work as well
- Would probably be easier to just write them out by hand

*Cut off a lot of the unnecessary bits*

**Index.tsx snippet mapping through data**

```
<Box
  component={Stack}
  direction="row"
  spacing={5}
>
{carouselData.map((item: CarouselProps) => (
  <CreativeCarousel
    src={item.src}
  />
))}
</Box>
```

**Carousel Component**

```
//Consistent typing for properties
export type CarouselProps = {
  src: StaticImageData;
};

const CreativeCarousel = (props: CarouselProps) => {
  return (
    <Card sx={{ maxWidth: 300, minWidth: 300, height: "100%" }}>
      <CardMedia component="img" height="75" image={props.src.src} />
    </Card>
  );
};
export default CreativeCarousel;
```

Comment: Hi - please consider creating a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to demonstrate your issue. Trying to debug performance issues in particular is very difficult without one.

Comment: Most definitely, sorry I'll clean up the unnecessary bits. I already fixed my issue but hopefully it helps someone else, I've been on this for a couple days 

Answer (score 1):

**Troubleshooting**
The lag went away after removing the `<CardMedia />` so my guess is that rerendering full-res images for every frame of scrolling isn't the most optimal move.

**Solution**

But replacing the underlying component from the standard html `img` to an optimized Next.js `Image` most definitely was. I was under the impression that I needed to pass a component as a property or else I'd need to use an `img` like what was used in [the example](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-card/#media). I only found out later that I could also pass react nodes as children in the [API page](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/card-media/#props).

```js
const Carousel = () => {
  return carouselData.map((item) => (
    <Card
      key={item.heading}
      sx={{ maxWidth: 300, minWidth: 300, height: "100%", mx: 4 }}
    >
      <CardMedia sx={{ width: "100%", height: "auto" }}>
        <Image
          alt={item.heading}
          src={item.src}
          layout="responsive"
        />
      </CardMedia>
    </Card>
  ));
};
export default Carousel;
```